# Using Snowflake with neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cloud, graph-databases, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to send data from snowflake to neo4j whenever newly transformed data is available in a snowflake table. What is the best way to do this? 
I am thinking of using snowalert to notify an updater service which will then pull new data from the snowflake table and push it to neo4j. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: You'll probably want to create a stream on the table(s) and consume the stream in your push to neo4J.

Comment: As Greg says above, you could leverage a stream to identify when data has changed.  To add onto that, depending on how you are moving data to neo4j, you could leverage a task to actually push the data to neo4j (COPY INTO, for example).  How do you currently load the data into neo4j?

Comment: Also, if you do have a service available, you could execute it from the task using Snowflake's new External Functions:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html

Comment: Thanks. A combination of streams and external functions looks promising. Loading data into neo4j can be modified if needed, currently, it is through CSV loading. Will there be a better alternative so that I can avoid creating an extra service and manage the pipeline with snowflake and neo4j alone?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a combination of methods from APOC library to load data from Snowflake to neo4j directly.
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.repeat/
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.periodic/apoc.periodic.iterate/
https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.load/apoc.load.jdbc/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.